# おいてきてしまった vs おいてしまってきた

Tags: grammar, nuances, conjugations, て-form

Is there any difference in the sentence when we mix the order of the conjugations in this sentence:

1) あいにく私はカメラを家においてきてしまった

2) あいにく私はカメラを家においてしまってきた

Or are both "correct" and mean the same thing with not much difference in nuance?

Comment: Presumably you're using きた to mean "came", and not "a gradual change".  Otherwise, neither would make sense.

Comment: @istrasci the original sentence is あいにく私はカメラを家においてきた (provided translation: *As it happens, I have left the camera at home.*) and i had this question while  pondering how we should add てしまう into that sentence

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example 1) is the natural one. It means that it was a mistake to come with the camera left at home. 2) is strange. It means, assuming it is grammatical, that it was a mistake to put/keep a camera at home, and came. I am not sure if it is even grammatical.

Comment: I think it's still correct, as in "Oh damn! When I went back home to , I left the camera there", supposing you initially had the camera in possession before going home.
Don't you think so?  But then "置いてしまってもどってきた" would be more natural (and less natural at the same time, as it's very heavy).